# How to use data events on cloned streams in cloneable-readable? : NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams, cloneable

I want to clone a read stream. Currently, I am doing it using [readable-stream-clone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloneable-readable) npm package. Using the code:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('smallTextFile.txt', { highWaterMark: 5 })
const ReadableStreamClone = require('readable-stream-clone')

const readStream1 = new ReadableStreamClone(readStream)
const readStream2 = new ReadableStreamClone(readStream)

readStream1.on('data', (chunk) => {
  console.log('1', chunk.toString())
})

readStream2.on('data', (chunk) => {
  console.log('2', chunk.toString())
})
```

Output of the code is:

```
1 This 
2 This 
1 is a 
2 is a 
1 small
2 small
1  reco
2  reco
1 rd
2 rd
```

Content in smallTextFile.txt:

```
This is a small record
```

But the problem with using `readable-stream-clone` is that it has only 3000 weekly downloads and it is not licensed.
There is another npm package [cloneable-readable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloneable-readable) it is a licensed package. Can anyone help me implement the above code using the [cloneable-readable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloneable-readable) package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code to do the same via cloneable-readable, it is similar to readable-stream-clone, when you wrap a steam in cloneable, it will give you a new stream in output.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('smallTextFile.txt', { highWaterMark: 5 })
const cloneable = require('cloneable-readable')

const readStream1 = cloneable(readStream);
const readStream2 = cloneable(readStream);

readStream1.on('data', (chunk) => {
  console.log('1', chunk.toString())
})

readStream2.on('data', (chunk) => {
  console.log('2', chunk.toString())
})
```